# Android app applies Function Twice

Tags: android, function

My code applies the function twice and I dont really know why?

CODE:

```
public void startClock()
{
    final TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    final TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
    new CountDownTimer(2000, 10) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long sec = ((millisUntilFinished / 10)/100);
            mTextField.setText(sec + ":" + ((millisUntilFinished / 10) - sec*100) );
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("0");
            iscore -= 2;
            score.setText(iscore + "");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

iscore = -4 at the end

When I run my program it goes inside onFinish() twice.

Why does onFinsh() function apply 2 times?

EDIT:

Found it. Called StartClock() twice in my code

Comment: are you sure you don't call startClock() twice?

Comment: thx))) I did , I checked my code and find out that I called it twice ))